# VLOOKUP on Python

Tags: python, dataframe, vlookup

I have got two dataframes:

```
df1: 

Index  a   b   c   d   e
1      1   X   10  12  A
2      1   Y   11  13  B
3      1   Z   12  14  C
4      1   W   13  15  C
5      1   A   14  49  D

df2: 

Index   b   f   
1       X   YES
2       Y   YES  
3       Z   YES
4       W   YES
```

I would like to VLOOKUP the values in column 'b' and report column 'f' to df1.
I tried running the following code but does not work:

`new_df = df1.merge(df2, on='b', how='left')`

My output should look like as follows:

```
Index  a   b   c   d   e  f
1      1   X   10  12  A  YES
2      1   Y   11  13  B  YES
3      1   Z   12  14  C  YES
4      1   W   13  15  C  YES
5      1   A   14  49  D  NaN
```

Note that df1 has 3400 rows, while df2 only 30.

Comment: The only difference I can see, is from the dup column, `df1.merge(df2.drop('Index',1), on='b', how='left')` gives the expected output

Comment: I get that all the b column values are renamed. I do not know if that should be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use list comprehension:

```
vlookup = ['Yes' if df['b'][i] in list(df2['b']) else np.nan for i in range(df.shape[0])]
```

Here is the output:

```
    df['vlookup'] = vlookup

    a   b   c   d   e   vlookup
0   1   X   10  12  A   Yes
1   1   Y   11  13  B   Yes
2   1   Z   12  14  C   Yes
3   1   W   13  15  C   Yes
4   1   A   14  49  D   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you can use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) using a pd.Series defined by df2 dataframe:

```
df1['f'] = df1['b'].map(df2.set_index('b')['f'])
df1
```

Output:

```
       a  b   c   d  e    f
Index                      
1      1  X  10  12  A  YES
2      1  Y  11  13  B  YES
3      1  Z  12  14  C  YES
4      1  W  13  15  C  YES
5      1  A  14  49  D  NaN
```

First create a pd.Series using `df2.set_index('b')['f']` then `map` the values in `df1['b']` to create the column `df1['f']`.